# setAttribute - set two random number values on a single attribute

Tags: javascript, attributes

I need to generate two random values on the same attribute.
Both numeric values between 5 and 35 to create random length dashed lines in SVG.

Here's the ideal output

```
<path stroke-dasharray="20 7" /> 
<path stroke-dasharray="9 27" /> 
<path stroke-dasharray="13 33" />
```

This is what i'm using to generate a single attribute value

```
    rect.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", Math.floor(Math.random() * 30 + 5));
```

Here it is in action https://jsfiddle.net/6a42rsty/
not that because there is only a single value in the stroke-dasharray attribute the lines and gaps are equal. they should be varied

What's the most efficient way to get two random values space separated ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
function getRandomNum(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 30 + 5);
}

rect.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", `${getRandomNum()} ${getRandomNum()}`);
```

Comment: Perfect, tested on the fiddle and it looks to work !  thanks :) 
https://jsfiddle.net/48j1L6kh/